# How can i know the position (x,y) of one cell in javafx?

Tags: javafx, position, draw

I´m doing a maze in JavaFX, I need to draw a line (Bresenham line) from the started point to home, and i need to know the position of both cells but idk how i can get the positions, i already use getLayout but it always return 0.0

this is my code of controller:

```
public void init(float numero){
    nume_obst = numero;
    //generate the maze
    for (int y = 0; y < Y_TILES; y++){
        for (int x=0; x < X_TILES; x++){
            Tiles tiles = new Tiles(x,y,Math.random() < nume_obst);
            grid[x][y] = tiles;
            pnMaze.getChildren().add(tiles);
        }
    }
}

public void setBtn(){
    if (btnHome.isFocused()){
        home = true;
        btnHome.setDisable(true);
    }

    if (btnPlayer.isFocused()){
        player = true;
        btnPlayer.setDisable(true);
    }

    if (btnStart.isFocused()){
        if (!btnHome.isDisable() && !btnPlayer.isDisable()){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("No puedes iniciar el juego si no has puesto la meta y el inicio del jugador");

            alert.show();
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

and this the code of the class tile, that draw each cell

```
 public class Tiles extends StackPane {
    private int x,y;
    private boolean obstacle;
    private  Label mountain = new Label();
    private double homeX,homeY;

    private Rectangle border = new Rectangle(TILE_SIZE - 2,TILE_SIZE - 2);

    public Tiles(int x,int y,boolean obstacle){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.obstacle = obstacle;



        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        border.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        mountain.setGraphic(obstacle ? new ImageView(imgObstacle) : null);

        getChildren().addAll(border,mountain);

        setTranslateX(x * TILE_SIZE);
        setTranslateY(y * TILE_SIZE);

        setOnMouseClicked(e -> setCharacters(getScene().getX(),getLayoutY()));
    }

    public void setCharacters(double x, double y){

        if (home){
            if (mountain.getGraphic() != null ){
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Advertencia");
                alert.setContentText("No puedes posicionar la meta sobre un obstaculo");

                alert.show();
            }else{
                homeX = x;
                homeY = y;
                mountain.setGraphic(obstacle ? new ImageView(imgObstacle) : new ImageView(imgHome));
                System.out.println();
                home=false;
            }
        }

        if (player){
            if (mountain.getGraphic() != null ){
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Advertencia");
                alert.setContentText("No puedes posicionar al jugador sobre un obstaculo");

                alert.show();
            }else {
                System.out.println(homeX);
                mountain.setGraphic(obstacle ? new ImageView(imgObstacle) : new ImageView(imgPlayer));
                player=false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `translateX`/`translateY` properties to place the tiles, those are the properties that are != 0 and you need to get them. Nodes are initialy placed at a location as determined by `layoutX`, `layoutY` but this location is modified by transforms such as translations to get the location the node is drawn to. BTW: you may want to consider making the parent a `GridPane` with appropriate column/row constraints, and use the background/border properties of `StackPane` since this will simplify the resizing / placement.

Comment: Furthemore note that `ImageView` is a node and you can replace it's image property with different value to replace the look. You can also pass `null` to make it invisible. Wrapping it in a `Label` is not necessary unless you need to use other properties of `Label` which doesn't seem to be the case here. Furthermore I recommend reusing existing nodes like your `ImageView` and avoid recreation. You could still detach it from the scene graph and set the image property to `null`, if you need...